# Fazer um clique no botão sem utilizar GUI

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em java e gostaria de fazer de uma forma mais organiza, então sem o uso da ferramenta do netBeans de clicar e arrastar, porém estou com muita dificuldade de fazer um simples clique no botão sair do sistema. Como fazer ?

Answer (score 1):

Qual é a dificuldade disso?

```java
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 * @author Victor
 */
public class TelaSair {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(TelaSair::criarTela);
    }

    private static void criarTela() {
        JFrame tela = new JFrame("Isto é uma tela");
        tela.setResizable(true);
        tela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton seuBotao = new JButton("Sair");
        seuBotao.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 30));
        tela.add(seuBotao);
        seuBotao.addActionListener(e -> tela.dispose());
        tela.pack();
        tela.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Compile e execute com o Java 8.